# Pimento sauce that is added to mayo

Tags: sauce

My mother would grow her own pimentos, then she would clean and cut them up and melt them down in a pot and slowly reduce them down to a thick sauce. Then she added other ingredients which I believe were raw eggs, but not sure.   When it was down she would refrigerate it then added it to mayo. You have never tasted potatoe salad like hers ever. This recipe is at least 50 yrs old and she never passed  this recipe down to to me before she passed away. Please, if you have any idea what I'm talking about please answer.

Comment: I don't see how this is a recipe recommendation. Looks like a user trying to identify what the recipe is in the first place. If you don't know what to call the product, it's difficult to find a recipe.